# Insert One to Many Relationship using Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I have a situation, where I want to insert data in Master (store_master) and Mapping (store_mapping) table in one to many relation using Room persistence Library. My implementation is below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "store_master")
class Store {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public var store_id: Int = 0

@SerializedName("name")
lateinit var store_name: String
}

@Entity(tableName = "store_mapping", foreignKeys = arrayOf(
    ForeignKey(entity = Store::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("store_id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("pic_id"),
            onDelete = CASCADE)))
class StorePicture(@field:PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
          @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int,
          @SerializedName("pic_id") var pic_id: Int?,
          @SerializedName("image") var storage_picture: String?)

 class StoreWithPictures {
    @Embedded
    var store: Store? = null

    @Relation(parentColumn = "store_id",
        entityColumn =  "pic_id")
    var pictures: List<StorePicture> = ArrayList()
}
```

For fetching Store with Pictures my implementation is below:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM store_master  ORDER BY store_master.storage_id DESC")
fun loadAll(): List<StoreWithPictures>
```

Above approach works fine for fetching data from master and mapping table, but I'm not able to insert in same fashion (i.e using @Embeded and @transaction annotations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue with `@Transaction` annotations.

```
 @Transaction
fun insertStoreWithPictures(store: Store, pictures: List<StorePicture>) {

    insertStore(store)
    insertPictures(pictures)

}
```

> Annotating a method with @Transaction makes sure that all database
>   operations you’re executing in that method will be run inside one
>   transaction. The transaction will fail when an exception is thrown in
>   the method body.